# three.js: how to clone object loaded using objmtl loader?

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

need to use same object multiple time for different render-er so how can i clone object? i tried using clone method but when i use same object for second render-er ,object from the first render-er got disappear.

```
 loader.load('object.obj', 'object.mtl', function (object) {
        array.push(object);
    });
```

later i use this array for different render-er like "array[0].clone()" but its not working?

can anyone guide me through this?

or give me a link to similer example.